# IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for UseAzureAppConfiguration

Tags: c#, azure, app-config, azure-app-configuration

I've been trying to implement feature managament in my Blazor app following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-aspnet-core?tabs=core5x#build-and-run-the-app-locally) and [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x) but for some reason my program refuses to accept "UseAzureAppConfiguration" even though I should have the proper usings and packages.

This is my Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.FeatureManagement;

namespace OreNoAppu
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
            services.AddAuthorization(options => options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy);

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
            services.AddFeatureManagement();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days.You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAzureAppConfiguration();     // "Does not contain definition" error.

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

These are my nugets:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BlazorPro.Spinkit" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="5.0.4" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="5.0.4" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Anyone have any idea why it can't find the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure App Configuration helps to manage application settings and control their access centrally. It’s built on the simple concept of key-value pairs, and this service provides manageability, availability, and ease-of-use.

To solve the problem you are facing please check if you are using the right library and also check **if you are having the following NuGet packages from Microsoft to work with an Azure App Configuration resource and the ability to use Feature Flags in the project**.

> **Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore**
> **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration**
> **Microsoft.FeatureManagement**

As you have added **FeatureManagement** by using statement in **Startup.cs**  and inside of **ConfigureServices**(...) added the ability to use it. Check if have modified the **Program.cs** and replaced the creation of default host builder with one that uses Azure App Configuration as shown below.

```
public  static  IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
     webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
     {
        var  settings = config.Build(); 
        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options => { 
            options.Connect(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString")) 
                    .ConfigureRefresh(refresh => { 
                            refresh.Register("Settings:Sentinel", refreshAll: true).SetCacheExpiration(new  TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)); 
                         }) 
                    .UseFeatureFlags(); 
        }); 
      }) 
      .UseStartup<Startup>());
```

Check this [How to Add Azure App Configuration and Feature Flags into Blazor in .Net 5](https://www.mcbeev.com/how-to-add-azure-app-configuration-and-feature-flags-into-blazor-in-net-5) document for detailed step by step explanation with example.

For more information also check the following documentations :

- [Use dynamic configuration in an ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-aspnet-core?tabs=core5x)
- [Adding Azure Feature Flags to ASP.NET Razor Pages Application](https://www.jasongaylord.com/blog/2020/06/08/adding-azure-feature-flags-to-aspnet-razor-pages-app)

Comment: It was the missing "Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore" package. I looked everywhere for the namespace of the method but didn't find anything. Anyway, your question is absolutely abhorrently written, so I won't upvote it.